# Why is CSS text color overriding placeholder color in IE 10?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, placeholder

Why is the `color` setting for `-ms-input-placeholder` is being overriden by the color setting for input fields? (`input[type=text],input[type=password], textarea, select`)

In Chrome and Firefox this works fine.

See image with blue placeholder text, even though `-ms-input-placeholder` is set to red.

[image: IE 10 Dev Tools]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chances are your `input[type=text]` selector appears after your `input:-ms-input-placeholder` selector in your stylesheet, which is causing it to take precedence (because both selectors are equally specific). If that's the case, you'll want to move the placeholder rule below in order for that to take precedence.

The most likely reason it works in Chrome and Firefox is because they both use a pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class, to target the placeholder text, which is something different altogether.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But why are both selectors equally specific? Logically, the placeholder is inside the input field.

Comment: @Joshua Fox: Since :-ms-input-placeholder is a pseudo-class, the selector is actually targeting the input and not the placeholder. The placeholder just inherits the color I think.

Comment: My issue was just that IE 10 was using "color" for the placeholder text. Why it does that is beyond me.